# Reach service through multiple internal addresses in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kube-dns, coredns

By default, in Kubernetes, an internal address is created when a service is deployed. It is possible to reach this service through the following address: `my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example` ([doc reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services))

I would like to add more internal addresses to this service when it gets deployed (I use helm to deploy my services). I want to be able to access the same service through `my-svc`, `my-svc-1` and `my-svc-2`. I was wondering if I could add these aliases into the deployment process so it automatically generates multiple entries for the same address.

As a workaround, I read that I can use CoreDNS and add CNAME entries but that's definitely not the optimal choice since I don't know if I can automatically add these entries into CoreDNS when I deploy the service. If that's possible, I'd be happy to know how it can be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution mentioned by Manuel is correct. I tested it and it works. I used the following yamls:

**Regular service expose:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: my-svc
  name: my-svc
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    run: my-svc
```

**ExternalName services:**

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-svc-1
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-svc-2
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
```

As expected, ExternalName type service creates CNAME records pointing to `my-svc`

```
$ dig my-svc-2 +search

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;my-svc-2.default.svc.cluster.local. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
my-svc-2.default.svc.cluster.local. 13 IN CNAME my-svc.default.svc.cluster.local.
my-svc.default.svc.cluster.local. 13 IN A       10.100.222.87
```

Comment: Thanks for testing my assumption.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't try it yet, but maybe you can add Service Type: ExternalName for my-svc-1, my-svc-2 and let them point to the my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example.

See documentation here: [service-external-name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname)

Comment: Very interesting, I will try that and will validate your answer if it works!